# How can I interpret the equation of the orbit in Schwarzschild metric?

Tags: general-relativity, orbital-motion, geodesics, differential-equations, intuition

Given the standard geodesic equation:
$$\frac{d^2 x^\mu}{d\lambda^2}+\Gamma ^\mu _{\sigma \rho}\frac{d x^\sigma}{d \lambda}\frac{d x^\rho}{d \lambda}=0$$
we want to apply it to the Schwarzschild metric; conceptually this simply means using the proper $\Gamma$ coefficients, but in practice this leads to a gargantuan calculation. But fortunately we can apply some simplification to get the following equation:
$$\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{dr}{d\lambda}\right)^2+V(r)=\mathcal{E} \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ (1)$$
where:
$$V(r)=\frac{1}{2}\epsilon-\epsilon\frac{GM}{r}+\frac{L^2}{2r^2}-\frac{GML^2}{r^3}$$
$$\mathcal{E}=\frac{1}{2}E^2$$
we should also specify that:

1. This equations should hold for massive and massless particles alike, so $\lambda$ is in one case the *proper time* and in the other an *affine parameter* of the proper time.
2. $r \equiv r(\lambda)$ which is the radius of the orbit
3. $\epsilon := -g_{\mu\nu}\frac{d x^\mu}{d\lambda}\frac{d x^\nu}{d\lambda}$
4. $E=\left(1-\frac{2GM}{r}\right)\frac{dt}{d\lambda}$
5. $L=r^2\frac{d \phi}{d\lambda}$ (where $\phi$ is the fourth coordinate in our Schwarzschild's spherical coordinates)

End of the setup; **my question is:** I followed the proof of this statement, involving killing vectors ecc., and I get the mathematical gist of it, but I have problems interpreting the result. **Is there an intuitive way to read statement (1)?**

(For example: One problem is that it is said that $V(\lambda)$ should represent the potential and $\mathcal{E}$ should represent the energy, but I don't see how.)

Comment: I do not understand precisely what intuition you are trying to gain here.

Comment: From what I understand now equation (1) just pops out of the calculations. I am interested in a more physical and less mathematical way to see equation (1). This equation seems to me like some sort of energy conservation, but I don't get how to relate the quantities to potential or kinetical energy for example.

Comment: Have a look at this page, particularly between equations (7.32) and (7.48).  The discussion on orbits continues further after this, but the derivation is in the range I give here.  https://ned.ipac.caltech.edu/level5/March01/Carroll3/Carroll7.html  There is also stuff in MTW if you have access to that ("the pit in the potential").

Comment: When you took classical mechanics, did you encounter the concept of the [effective potential](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Effective_potential) for Keplerian orbits?

Comment: *Is there an intuitive way to read statement (1)?* Since you used the word “statement”, some readers will think you are talking about the numbered paragraph rather than the numbered equation.

Comment: *this leads to a gargantuan calculation* No, it doesn’t, because the Schwarzschild metric has only five nonzero metric derivatives ($g_{tt,r}$, $g_{rr,r}$, $g_{\theta\theta,r}$, $g_{\phi\phi,r}$, and $g_{\phi\phi,\theta}$) and the Christoffel symbols are symmetric. Only 9 of the 40 Christoffels require any algebra.

Comment: Are you familiar with the concept of an effective potential? It appears in many more situations than this one.

Answer (score 1):

1. OP's first-order ODE (3) involves 4 spacetime coordinates, but after using various Killing symmetries of the Schwarzschild solution, we eliminate$^1$ 3 coordinates, and we are left with OP's first-order ODE (1) in a single radial coordinate $r$, which readily has an interpretation as a non-relativistic-looking$^2$ 1D energy conservation law. See also my related Phys.SE answer [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/462759/2451).
2. An additional existence argument comes from the fact that we know from the Kepler problem that some version of OP's eq. (1) must exist in the non-relativistic limit $c\to \infty$.

--

$^1$ Explicitly this elimination is done by (i) going to equatorial plane, and by using that (ii) specific energy & (iii) angular momentum are conserved.

$^2$ While the "kinetic term" $\dot{r}^2$ naively looks non-relativistic, everything is of course fully relativistic!