# Gravitational Effect on Photon

Tags: gravity, visible-light, photons

It is known that photons are massless particles. So why is light affected by the strong gravitational field of black holes?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can gravity affect light?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/130552/)