# What is the gravitational pull of a photon?

Tags: electromagnetism, energy, gravity, photons, mass

I know it may seem like a stupid question, but I recently found out that because a photon has energy (obviously) then it must have a gravitational pull. I was wondering exactly what this gravitational pull is. It must be tiny because we are constantly being bombarded with photons every millisecond of our lives. Here is a [link to the original question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/22876/) that has been answered Yes 3 times.

Comment: Maybe this question will help https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/161815/

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/130552/2451 and links therein.