# Photons and gravity

Tags: gravity, photons, laser

A very powerful laser pointing to the empty space next to small object in space. The photons in the laser beam does not hit the object.

Will the small object be gravitationally affected by that laser beam?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Do two beams of light attract each other in general theory of relativity?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/6197/)

Comment: The other question asks about light-light interaction, whereas this is light-mass. I'm leaning toward 'not duplicate'.

Comment: Possible duplicates: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/22876/2451 and links therein.