# Gravity will bend light. But will bent/curved light create gravity?

Tags: gravity, visible-light, gravitational-lensing

The first bit is well documented. Einstein (and others) supposed that gravity could bend light. We first observed it around the sun at total solar eclipse, and now it is a [tool for astronomers and physicists alike](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravitational_lens).

But I cannot find anything supposing the reverse. Mechanics aside, *if* we could bend light, is there anything saying that it would or would not create a gravitational field?

My assumptions are this:

1. A smaller radius of curvature would create a larger gravitational field

   This makes sense. In gravitational lensing, a larger gravitational field will result in greater bending/curving of a light beam. Hence why we cannot detect light being bent by a mosquito.
2. A more powerful beam of light - curved/bent with an identical radius of curvature to a weaker beam - would create a larger gravitational field than said weaker beam

   It has been years since my physics days, and so I am unsure of this second assumption. That is to say, I cannot recall if the inverse is true (that a higher energy beam of light will bend/curve less for a given gravitational field). A couple quick searches [show no dependency on energy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravitational_lensing_formalism) of a beam of light, when calculating deflection due to gravitational lensing.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How would you bend the light without a gravitational field?

Comment: Possible duplicates: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/22876/2451 , http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/6197/2451 and links therein.

Comment: You could use refraction to bend it.

Comment: Yes, but the effect is so small that (like with the mosquito) you will never observe it.

Comment: Light already creates a gravitational field all by itself, no bending required.

Comment: Why should bending "create" gravity? In general relativity what "creates" gravity is energy distribution expressed by the [stress–energy tensor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stress%E2%80%93energy_tensor), so bending would affect curvature only to the extent that it rearranges energy. Your question can also be interpreted as purely mathematical, namely does stronger field bend light more. In that case the answer is yes, but the order of causality is reversed. There is no "creation" there, like fire accompanies smoke but it is not created by it.

Comment: @NoethersOneRing did you read the whole post? I, quite literally, mentioned that *Mechanics aside...*. This is a thought experiment, based on what we know and theorize.

Comment: @LewisMiller do you have a link or anything you can point me to? You say *yes*, others say *no*. Not very helpful beyond conspiracy. But, to continue on with your answer, why would it be unobservable? The radius of curvature that an entire galaxy can bend light is enormous, so why wouldn't bending light to a smaller (i.e. desktop-sized) radius not produce a greater field?

Comment: @Javier Ok, but that isn't the question at hand. A beam of light powerful enough to produce an appreciable amount of gravity (exclusively from photons' inherent gravity) is arguably impossible to create, with all of the energy the universe could muster. What is the total gravitational pull by the sun's photons, assuming that every photon for one second were confined to the same location?

Comment: @Conifold No particular reason that it would *create* gravity. Not all processes (if any) are reversible, but many are very nearly. For instance, the photoelectric effect is essentially a mirror image of an LED producing light. So, perhaps the mechanism between gravity and light bending has a mirror process.

Comment: @Qmechanic not a duplicate question. Those deal with individual photons exerting gravity (whether confined to a single point, or allowed to travel). In either case, the light is not curving. I am not interested in the gravitational field due to a single photon at rest or traveling in a straight line, but rather the effect of (somehow...) curving light.

Comment: Light, whether bent or not, has energy and will contribute to the stress-energy tensor of GR. But to have an observable effect like that of an astronomical object it would need to have an incredible energy density.