# Do anti-parallel photons affect each other gravitationally?

Tags: general-relativity, electromagnetic-radiation, gravity, photons

We know that two parallel photons have no gravitational effect on each other because they never pass through each other's light cone.  The question is, what happens to anti-parallel photons?  It stands to reason they pass through each other's light cone at some point after they pass each other giving an opportunity to exchange energy and bend their paths.  What confuses me however is if the photons are exactly the same color do they redshift each other as if they both redshifted this would lead to missing energy.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Do two beams of light attract each other in general theory of relativity?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/6197/)

Comment: Yes, but I'm not sure this is a duplicate question.  By coincidence a different question had an answer that was relevant.